# XSLT Merging Data

Tags: xslt

I have an xml file with two "sets" of data that I need to merge into a table showing old vs new. I'm doing this by processing only new data, and for each piece of new data, grabbing the accompanying old piece. My question is how to properly store my current position in the new set so that I can grab the matching data from the old set. The real challenge I'm having is around nested elements, where position() isn't as useful. So, given the following simplified xml, where I know 100% for sure that there will be a perfectly matching tag set in New and Old...

```
<doc>
   <New>
      <Para>New info 1</Para>
      <Para>New info 2</Para>
      <List>
         <Li>New Point 1</Li>
         <Li>New Point 2</Li>
         <Li>New Point 3</Li>
      </List>
      <Para>New info 3</Para>
      <List>
         <Li>New Point 4</Li>
         <Li>New Point 5</Li>
         <Li>New Point 6
            <List>
               <Li>New nested Point 1</Li>
               <Li>New nested Point 2</Li>
               <Li>New nested Point 3</Li>
            </List>
         </Li>
      </List>
   </New>
   <Old>
      <Para>Old info 1</Para>
      <Para>Old info 2</Para>
      <List>
         <Li>Old Point 1</Li>
         <Li>Old Point 2</Li>
         <Li>Old Point 3</Li>
      </List>
      <Para>Old info 3</Para>
      <List>
         <Li>Old Point 4</Li>
         <Li>Old Point 5</Li>
         <Li>Old Point 6
            <List>
               <Li>Old nested Point 1</Li>
               <Li>Old nested Point 2</Li>
               <Li>Old nested Point 3</Li>
            </List>
         </Li>
      </List>
   </Old>
```

I want to merge and output the info in an html-like table.

```
  <table>
     <row>
        <entry>New Info 1</entry>
        <entry>Old Info 1</entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>New Info 2</entry>
        <entry>Old Info 2</entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New Point 1</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old Point 1</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New Point 2</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old Point 2</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New Point 3</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old Point 3</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>New Info 3</entry>
        <entry>Old Info 3</entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New Point 4</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old Point 4</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New Point 5</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old Point 5</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New Point 6</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old Point 6</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New nested Point 1</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old nested Point 1</li >
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New nested Point 2</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old nested Point 2</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
     <row>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>New nested Point 3</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <list>
              <li>Old nested Point 3</li>
           </list>
        </entry>
     </row>
  </table>
```

It's only nested elements that are problematic. For everything else I can store my position within <New> and apply templates on the corresponding <Old> data, but position() becomes less useful when nested.

Any ideas on how to effectively store my position within <New> so that I can process the matching <Old> element? I'm using XSLT 1.

Comment: I don't understand your output. Where did the values `"New List 1"` and `"New List 2 + Nested list " ` come from?

Comment: I was trying to be brief and show that I need the list content and the nested list content. I'll update to be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your example only deals with the top-level elements in each branch, the requested result can be accomplished by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="old" match="id" use="." />

<xsl:variable name="old" select="/doc/Old" />

<xsl:template match="/doc">

    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="New/Para | New/List"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Para">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::Para)" />
    <row>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="$old/Para[$i + 1]"/>
        </entry>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="List">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::List)" />
    <row>
        <entry>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$old/List[$i + 1]"/>
        </entry>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Matching individual leaf nodes by their position in their respective tree would be much more complicated, I think.

---

### Edit:

> I do need to match individual nodes unfortunately.

As I said, this is going to be much more complex - especially since you cannot use an extension function to dynamically evaluate a string into a path expression.

Here, we'll do a preliminary pass to process nodes in the `Old` branch and assign them a `path` attribute. This will enable us to call them by this attribute when processing the nodes in the `New` branch for the final output:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- first-pass -->
<xsl:variable name="old">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/doc/Old" mode="old"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="old-set" select="exsl:node-set($old)" />

<xsl:template match="Para | Li" mode="old">
    <node>
        <xsl:attribute name="path">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])" />
                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])" />
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </node>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="old"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- output -->
<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="New"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Para | Li">
    <xsl:variable name="path">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])" />
            <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])" />
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="old-path" select="concat('doc[0]/Old[0]/', substring-after($path, 'doc[0]/New[0]/'))" />
    <row>   
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="$old-set/node[@path=$old-path]"/>
        </entry>
    </row>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
   <row>
      <entry>New info 1</entry>
      <entry>Old info 1</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New info 2</entry>
      <entry>Old info 2</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New Point 1</entry>
      <entry>Old Point 1</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New Point 2</entry>
      <entry>Old Point 2</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New Point 3</entry>
      <entry>Old Point 3</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New info 3</entry>
      <entry>Old info 3</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New Point 4</entry>
      <entry>Old Point 4</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New Point 5</entry>
      <entry>Old Point 5</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New Point 6
            </entry>
      <entry>Old Point 6
            </entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New nested Point 1</entry>
      <entry>Old nested Point 1</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New nested Point 2</entry>
      <entry>Old nested Point 2</entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>New nested Point 3</entry>
      <entry>Old nested Point 3</entry>
   </row>
</table>
```

Comment: I do need to match individual nodes unfortunately. I've updated the output accordingly. Basically every time there is an element in <New> I need to immediately process its counterpart in <Old>

Comment: @user3198443 Which specific XSLT processor are you using? You might be able to benefit from using an extension function.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I'm using msxml unfortunately.

Comment: I didn't see that there was an updated answer. Thanks for all the help.