# Change the value of first XML - dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to ask you for some advice/help how to manage with my problem. Honestly I am not sure if it is even possible by using XSL transformation. But maybe some of you know the answer. (Unfortanely I'm xsl newbie)

So,I have XML Input which looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag1>
                <tag2>sometext</tag2>
                <tag3>234</tag3>
                <tag4>2344</tag4>
                <tag5>abcd</tag5>
</tag1>
<tag1>
    <tag3>657</tag3>
<tag2>
```

I would like to do some XSL transformation which transform that structure into:

```
<tag1>
                <tag2>sometext</tag2>
                <tag3>657</tag3>
                <tag4>2344</tag4>
                <tag5>abcd</tag5>
</tag1>
```

As you can see value from TAG3 (from second XML) change the value of first `<tag3></tag3>.`
Unfortanely it should works dynamically. I mean that I don't know exactly what will be the name of tags.

If it is possible, for me steps should looks like:
Step 1: Looking for same tags name between XML2 and XML1
Step 2: Change the value from XML2 to XML1

If it's not possible to do dynamically maybe it's possible to do statically?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT. An XML document must have a single root element. And XML declaration is allowed only at the start of the document. And your tags don't match.

Comment: Hello michael, ok you are right, I try to have appropriate XML structure. I edited my question. Now there is only one "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"

Comment: But it's still not XML, because there are two root elements **and** the tags do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can pre-process your input into a **well-formed** XML such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <tag1>
      <tag2>sometext</tag2>
      <tag3>234</tag3>
      <tag4>2344</tag4>
      <tag5>abcd</tag5>
   </tag1>
   <tag1>
      <tag3>657</tag3>
   </tag1>
</root>
```

you could then apply a stylesheet like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="corrections" select="/root/*[2]/*" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/*/*">
    <xsl:variable name="correction" select="$corrections[name()=name(current())]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$correction">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$correction"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag1>
  <tag2>sometext</tag2>
  <tag3>657</tag3>
  <tag4>2344</tag4>
  <tag5>abcd</tag5>
</tag1>
```

Note that this assumes all the "corrections" are immediate children of the second child of the root element (`tag1[2]` in this example). Otherwise it gets much more complicated - see a similar problem here: [XSLT Merging Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889356/xslt-merging-data/32890764#32890764)