# Compare two xml files with XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have two XML files, file1.xml and file2.xml.
I want to compare these two files and write in the file3.txt the difference of contents.

It doesn't work because I have an synthax error with $file2/[not(@key=$key1)]

How can I solve that ?

**File 1**

```
<node key="U">
  <node key="E" value="E1"/>
  <node key="B" value="B1"/>
  <node key="Z" value="Z1"/>
  <node key="T">
    <node key="Y">
      <node key="H" value="H1"/>
      <node key="C" value="C1"/>
      <node key="P" value="P1"/>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
```

****File 2**** **

```
<node key="U">
  <node key="E" value="E1"/>
  <node key="B" value="O1"/>
  <node key="G" value="Z1"/>
  <node key="T">
    <node key="Y2">
      <node key="H" value="H1"/>
      <node key="C1" value="C8"/>
      <node key="P" value="P1"/>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file2.xml')" />

<xsl:variable name="key1" select="@key" />
<xsl:variable name="key2" select="@key" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:comment>"only in file1"</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="[not(@key=$key2)]"/>
    <xsl:comment>"only in file2"</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$file2/[not(@key=$key1)]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Java Code**

```
package XSLT;

import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MainCompare {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform2.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("file1.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("file3.txt")));
    }
}
```

I would like to get differences between the two XML files.

Result wanted

> ```
> "only in file1"
>
>  key="B" value="B1"
>  key="Z" value="Z1"
>  key="Y"
>  key="C" value="C1"
>
> "only in file2"
>
>   key="B" value="O1"
>   key="G" value="Z1"
>   key="Y2"
>   key="C1" value="C8"
> ```

Comment: I doubt very much XSLT is the right tool for this.

Comment: Yes, xml unit must be more useful but i already use xslt to sort xml files. So i would like to use xslt again to show differences between the two files sorted.

Comment: Well, it cannot work the way you imagine. And I am not sure it can work at all. You did not explain what are the rules for the comparison or even what is the expected result. If the 2 documents have *exactly* the same structure, and the only differences you are looking for are in the values of the `key` and `value` attributes of corresponding nodes, then it *might* be possible - but it won't be easy (esp. not in XSLT 1.0).

Comment: Yes, the structure is the same.

Comment: Here is something quite similar that you could adapt to your situation. Though I would still advise against it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32890764/3016153

Comment: Thank you but I don't know how to do otherwise because with XMLUnit1 the result done is not clear for me and with java it seems difficult to make with hashmap .

Comment: I rolled your question back to the original, after you have (quite correctly) posted a new one with the changed requirements.

Comment: Yes, i would like to better explain the problem. So i posted a new message but it has been deleted. How better explain because my edit has also been deleted.

Comment: I have reopened your other question. But I must tell you that you are not explaining the logic very well (at least not well enough for me to understand it).

Comment: I edited it. I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something relatively simple I managed to put together quickly. The result format is different from what you show - but I see no good reason to perform the same comparison twice. (If you want, you could put the result in a variable and then "print" it out twice, once for each side).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="v1" select="//node" />
<xsl:variable name="v2" select="document('file2.xml')//node" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <differences>
        <xsl:for-each select="$v1">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="n2" select="$v2[$i]" />
            <xsl:if test="@key != $n2/@key or @value != $n2/@value">
                <diff key1="{@key}" key2="{$n2/@key}" value1="{@value}" value2="{$n2/@value}"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </differences>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<differences>
   <diff key1="B" key2="B" value1="B1" value2="O1"/>
   <diff key1="Z" key2="G" value1="Z1" value2="Z1"/>
   <diff key1="Y" key2="Y2" value1="" value2=""/>
   <diff key1="C" key2="C1" value1="C1" value2="C8"/>
</differences>
```

Comment: It works well thank you for your help. I will post an other question because  i don't think it will work again if one Key is missing from one side ? with this try, i think a Line of file1 is compared with the same Line of file2. If i iterate &i  perhaps it could be possible to check all the Lines of file2 for each Line of file1.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by  "one Key is missing from one side".  The way this works is that each `Node` is assigned a serial number based on the order in which it appears in the XML. Then each pair of `Node`s with the same serial number is compared - and if they don't have the same values in their `key` and `value` attributes, a `Diff` is created. If one `Node` in a pair has a `key` value and the other one doesn't, then they are not the same.

Comment: I have written an edit. Your first try with XSLT3.0 was already a good try for me but the next one is not suited to my problem as I have tried to explain it in my edit post.

Comment: I said in my comment to your question that this might be possible if the 2 documents have *exactly* the same structure. You replied that yes, the structure is the same. This is NOT true in your new example - and we are back at the beginning where the logic that needs to be applied is not clear. If you want to compare the `Node`s based on matching `key` values, **regardless of where in the hierarchy the `Node` is**, then this is a completely different problem and you should have posted it in a new question. And of course, this can only work if the `key` values are unique.

Comment: Note also that I did NOT post the XSLT 3.0 suggested solution.

Comment: When I said the structure is the same, I wanted to say that all the keys are sorted by algebraic order. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Java it is usually possible to use Saxon HE (currently supported versions are 10, 11, 12) and XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="key" match="*" use="@key, @value" composite="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>"only in file1"&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="//*[not(key('key', (@key, @value), $file2))]!('key: ' || @key || ' value : ' || @value)" separator="&#10;"/>
<xsl:text>&#10;"only in file"&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$file2//*[not(key('key', (@key, @value), current()))]!('key: ' || @key || ' value : ' || @value)" separator="&#10;"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:variable name="file2" select="doc('file2.xml')"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
"only in file1"
key: B value : B1
key: Z value : Z1
key: Y value : 
key: C value : C1
"only in file"
key: B value : O1
key: G value : Z1
key: Y2 value : 
key: C1 value : C8
```

Comment: I don't think this implements the requested logic: what if a node with the same key and value exists in another position?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, if you happen to know or understand the "requested logic", good for you, I tried to make sense of the sample result together with the sample input, nothing more and nothing less. What "logic" is behind a code sample doing e.g `<xsl:comment>"only in file1"</xsl:comment>`  and `<xsl:comment>"only in file2"</xsl:comment>` in a template matching `@* | node()` and pretending to do some recursive processing but ending up with a single `"only in file1"` listing some values followed by a single `"only in file2"` listing some other values?

Comment: Good try thank you but I can't go with XSLT3 because my project can't have external jar.

Comment: is it possible for you to transform your code with the XSLT1 version ?

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> I have an synthax error with $file2/[not(@key=$key1)]

Well, yes, that isn't a valid XPath expression. I can't offer an immediate correction, because I've no idea what it was intended to do. And when I look at the rest of your stylesheet, it's full of similar errors that suggest you haven't mastered the basics. I'm afraid my immediate reaction is, only someone with a much better knowledge of XPath should be attempting a task as complex as this.

Unlike @michael.hor257k, I think that XSLT is a perfectly good tool for this job, especially later versions such as XSLT 3.0. However, there are two big jobs to do before you start coding: one is to define the requirements much more precisely, and the second is to learn XSLT. I would recommend writing some simpler XSLT stylesheets before you tackle a difficult one like this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have written an edit to be clearer. Unfortunately, I can't use XSLT 3.0. Only XSLT1.0 is possible. I hope my description is enough clear.